# Python Django admin iterate and display

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I am trying to find a way where I need to display the custom result in my Django admin section for that I have this dataset:

[Gist link to my data](https://gist.github.com/nwoow/8dc967924bcdc31f64e53eed9a958e3e)

In my code section, I can get this data using this code in Django admin:

```
def question_00(self, obj):
    return obj.data["0"]["question"]

def answer_00(self, obj):
    return obj.data["0"]["answer"]
```

And I am displaying that data using this code:

```
fieldsets = (
    (None, {
        'fields': (
        ('question_00','answer_00'),
        )
    }),
)
```

My whole code is like this:

```py
class SurveyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['user_id','question_answer']
    def question_00(self, obj):
        return obj.data["0"]["question"]

    def answer_00(self, obj):
        return obj.data["0"]["answer"]

    fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'fields': (
            ('question_00','answer_00'),
            )
        }),
    )

    readonly_fields = ["question_00","user_id","answer_00"]
```

Everything is fine all is working if I need to create this system through iteration how can I get a result like this:

Where it create a functions like:

```
def question_00(self, obj):
    return obj.data["0"]["question"]

def question_01(self, obj):
    return obj.data["1"]["question"]
......
```

And answer like this:

```
def answer_00(self, obj):
    return obj.data["0"]["answer"]
def answer_01(self, obj):
    return obj.data["1"]["answer"]
```

And it should populate data like this in fieldset:

```
fieldsets = (
    (None, {
        'fields': (
        ('question_00','answer_00'),
        ('question_01','answer_01'),
        ......
        )
    }),
)
```

It looks simple but I am trying to do it admin.py file what is the best solution for this problem.

Comment: Can you share your survey model as well please?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/nwoow/51e7892ed4b2ae166415a0f2cea4a9bb   Objective is very simple to run a loop and display function and add in array but I can't create the function inside a loop.

Comment: why don't you consider splitting "data" into two-> 1.questions and 2.answers?

Comment: It is complicated I am saving data as a json format in db. I need to display from that json data.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to make a generic numbers of fields based on your object's data in admin display. (at least without overriding admin template)

Since you want a simple solution, the closest one came to my mind is add a simple html tag and display the question and answer as a list-like column.

```
from django.utils.html import format_html_join
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

class SurveyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def question_and_answers(self, instance):
        values = [y for x, y in instance.data.items()]
        return format_html_join(
            mark_safe('<br>'),
            '{}-{}',
            ((item['answer'],item['question']) 
             for item in values),
        )

    fieldsets = ((None, {
        'fields': (question_and_answers,)   
        }),
    )
```

Comment: the instance how do I implement this code in my admin

Comment: Added this code but getting error instance not define type

Comment: are you sure you are adding this method under your admin class?

Comment: I am getting this erro sequence item 0: expected str instance, function found

Comment: Getting SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Again getting error: sequence item 0: expected str instance, function found